# Change tint color for a specific view when custom tintColor is set for all views in appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm trying to change the `tintColor` on a `segmentControl` through storyboard. But, unfortunately in my AppDelegate I'm setting a default `tintColor` for all views in my app.

**In AppDelegate:**

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = .myCustomColor
```

This will always override all my other changes. So for instance, if I set a another `tintColor` through either storyboard or programmatically on my `segmentControl`, it won't have any affect. Is it possible to solve this without removing my code in appDelegate?

Comment: Where do you override the value by code? Try doing it in `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: @Larme I tried it out in `viewDidAppear()` but nothing happens :/

Comment: In AppDelegate have you tried changing it to `window?.tintColor = .myCustomColor`. That should allow you to customise tintColors in controls in the storyboard.

Comment: @JonJ Thank you! It worked perfectly. Feel free to set it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the global tint color but still allow for different tints in controls or views, just set:

```
window?.tintColor = .myCustomColor
```

in the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function of `AppDelegate`.

Comment: For this to work, the storyboard tintColor must be set to Default.

Answer (score 0):

To set the tint color for all windows you can use :

```
window?.tintColor = UIColor.gray
```